# What capability is required to view posts, scheduled in the future, by someone else?

Tags: customization, permissions, user-roles

So, I'm trying to create a number of custom roles within my theme to meet with the custom requirements of the site.

The first, and most simple, being 'external viewer' who I want to simply be able to view posts (both built in and custom post-types) that someone else on the content team has created and scheduled for some point in the future.

### Initially I tried this

```
$viewer_capabilities = array(
    'read_private_pages' => true,
    'read_private_posts' => true,
    'read' => true
);


add_role('external_viewer', 'External Viewer', $viewer_capabilities );
```

But when logging into `/wp-admin` I just got the 'no permission' message and I couldn't do anything. If I went to one of the scheduled posts, I just got 'not found'.

### So then I tried

```
$role_object = get_role( 'external_viewer' );
$role_object->add_cap( 'read_private_pages' );
$role_object->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' );
$role_object->add_cap( 'read' );
```

Which got me a little further. I can login and see the admin dashboard, but if I visit a scheduled post, then I still get 'page not found'.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found *Future posts* are not exactly a different capability.

In [WordPress Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) I found `edit_others_posts` is available by default for Super Admin, Administrator and Editor. I think it will be a right way you can proceed. (Not tested though)

And additionally try with `edit_published_posts`, `publish_posts` etc.